# independence statistics and combination

Tags: probability, combinations

**QUESTION**

The recovery rate from the common eye disease for a student is 0.9, if 4 students have this diseases what is the probability that exactly one will recover (assume independence)

**ANSWER**

4C1 * 0.9 * 0.1 *0.1 *0.1 = 0.0036

can somebody please explain me how this answer came to be

Comment: Line up the people in order of student number. Write R for recover, N for not recover. There are $4$ patterns in which exactly one recovers, RNNN, NRNN, NNRN, NNNR. Compute the probability of each and add.

Comment: i do not understand you

Comment: The probability of RNNN is $(0.9)(0.1)(0.1)(0.1)$. The probability of NRNN is $(0.1)(0.9)(0.1)(0.1)$, the same. Do the other two.

Comment: okay i get it thanks

Comment: You are welcome. For more general stuff of the same kind (but you are probably not yet there in your course) please see the *binomial distribution*.